# WSO2 - Docusign Connector

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I want to integrate with DocuSign and I found the wso2 connector for DocuSign 1.0.9 version.

The DocuSign connector has not been updated for some time now and I did not see the OAuth2 authentication capabilities there with the impersonation option.

1. Is this connector up-to-date and would work with wso2ei 6.4.0?
2. Is there another connector for DocuSign?

Best,
Pratyush

Answer (score 0):

As per the connector store description for this connector this supports the EI 6.4.0 version. It seems that this is the only available connector for DocuSign.

Can you please check the documentation [2] this seems to be supporting OAuth2 authentication.

[1]-https://store.wso2.com/store/assets/esbconnector/details/335702ff-8e66-4a57-9e0a-b189aa4c50d2
[2]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Configuring+DocuSign+Operations